# file versioning control using java.

Tags: versioning

My requirement is,In my project,i maintained a folder which have set of images which are uploaded by user.but user can upload same named image n number of times.to overcome this overhead i planned to maintain versioning to each image which are same (same named). please advice me right solution –

Comment: possible duplicate of your own question an hour earlier [versioning control using java programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252731/versioning-control-using-java-programming)

Answer (score 0):

There is no right solution for all purposes. You can build version control yourselg, renaming old files  ans moving them to separate subdirectory, or you can tap existing version control systems like git / svn / cvs / rcs / ccss / mercurial  - some of them have java libraries available and they all suck to different extent.   Just pick one that you like.

Another alternative would be to use some CMS system, but usually they suck ever more.

Why do you need to keep track of older versions anyway?

Comment: Honestly, using version control system to handle this kind of task is an obvious overkill.

Comment: basically he needs to invent - kind of version kontrol system - so why not choose something that is lightweight enough and does not suck? Pushing blobs to database  or handling copying and renaming  files and keeping track of versions is kind of overkill also.

Answer (score 0):

How about indexing them all using the database (if you have one)?

When an user uploads the file, save it with some scrambled name like `funnycat-12345timestamp12345.jpg`. Then store the upload date, original name and file name in the database. Now, whenever you need a file with name "funnycat.jpg", you do a query `SELECT * FROM files WHERE original_name='funnycat.jpg' ORDER BY upload_date DESC`, and you have whole revision history for that file.